# getAnnotation() in Class vs Class<?> instances

Tags: java, generics

I have noticed an interesting difference between the following cases, but cannot explain it:

```
//this works
Class<?> myClass = Class.class;
MyAnnotation myAnnotation = myClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);

//this does not work
Class myClass = Class.class;//note this is not generic anymore
MyAnnotation myAnnotation = myClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);//it says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Annotation to MyAnnotation
```

So basically in the first case the same type is returned, and in the second, the Annotation type is returned.

Could someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of mehod `getAnnotation` looks like this:

```
public <A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationClass)
```

Now the difference between the 2 calls is, you are using raw type `Class` for `myClass` in 2nd code. When you use raw type for a generic type, all the generic type information is erased, and the compiler will see only the erasure of the method `getAnnotation` for that particular reference, which is:

```
public Annotation getAnnotation(Class annotationClass)
```

So, it returns `Annotation`, and not `MyAnnotation`. From [JLS §4.6 - Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6):

> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

Whereas, in case of using `Class<?>`, the type parameter `A` will be inferred as `MyAnnotation` from the parameter you are passing to the method - `Class<MyAnnotation>`. So, the return type of method is seen as `MyAnnotation`.

See [JLS § 4.8 - Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) `M` of a raw type `C` that is not inherited from
>   its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds
>   to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to
>   `C`.